# Closed-Form Modular Arithmetic

Tags: functions, modular-arithmetic, closed-form, arithmetic-functions

Is there a way to define *modulo division* (or functions of modular arithmetic in general) as superposition of (elementary?) functions?

For example, the multiplication is first introduced as summation, the exponentiation - as multiplication, etc. The trigonometric functions can be expressed  through other elementary functions. Moreover, a wide range of "continuous" functions can be expressed as infinite series of different nature, whether we are talking about complete set of functions in $L_p$ space, or about derivatives of infinitely differentiable function combined in Taylor series.

I wonder if it is possible to define functions from modulo arithmetics as closed-form expressions  of functions which belong to classes listed in the table below. I have no doubts that it is possible to do so via infinite series, although I do not know how. However, I am particularly interested in closed-form expressions from the table

[image]

I find this table from [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression#Comparison_of_different_classes_of_expressions) extremely interesting, although it is devoted to the closed-form expressions only and missing modulo arithmetic.

Answer (score 4):

I believe what you are looking for is this:

$$ x \bmod M = [\frac{1}{2} + \frac{i}{2\pi}\ln(-e^{-i2\pi x/M})]\times M $$

You can check it out graphed [here:](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20(1%2F2%20%2B%20(i%2F(2*pi))*log(-1*exp(-i*2*pi*x%2FM)))*M%20where%20M%20%3D%2010)

I stumbled upon this post because I was playing around with the function $(-1)^x$ which has a real and imaginary part that are periodic and out of phase.  Using Euler's formula I pulled out the part of the function that was cyclical and graphed it and saw that it was a saw wave.  I generalized it by scaling it in the x and y direction by M.

Here is the Euler formula transform of the same function:

$$ x \bmod M = [\pi + \frac{\ln(\cos(\frac{2\pi (x+M/2)}{M}+M+\ln(2))+i*\sin(\frac{2\pi (x+M/2)}{M}+M+\log(2)))}{i}]\times \frac{M}{2\pi} $$

You can also derive this by taking the closed form solution that drops out of the [infinite Fourier series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeriesSawtoothWave.html):

Note that the Gibbs phenomenon that you get with a finite number of terms when approximating the saw wave disappears with the closed form solution.

Comment: This website uses [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for math formulas and symbols.

Comment: I converted it to MathJax.

Answer (score 2):

Though it isn't perfect, you can create a "saw-tooth" function which is pretty much a periodic linear function. For example, if you want to take $\mod 3$, you have the function $f$ which has period $3$ and looks like $f(x) = x$ for $x \in [0, 3)$.

You can approximate this saw-tooth function using a Fourier series which involves harmonics of the form $e^{2 \pi i n x}$.