# How to express the rest of division by three, with very elementary functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic, provability

Is it possible to express 
$\; "\!n\pmod 3\!"\;$ 
with combinations of the functions plus, minus, multiplication, division and exponentiation in $\mathbb C$ or preferably in $\mathbb Z[i]$?

I'ts not allowed with modulo or integer parts, and the inverses are only valid if they can be expressed as above. Also all sums, products etc must be finite.

There is a simular question [Closed-Form Modular Arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1358921/closed-form-modular-arithmetic) where trigonometric functions and logarithms are allowed.

If it isn't possible, how to prove that?

Comment: Are complex constants allowed? $(\frac12+\frac12\sqrt3 i)^n + (\frac12-\frac12\sqrt3 i)^n$ will give you something of period $3$.

Comment: Same idea as Henning. Do Lagrange interpolation (or inverse DFT) to find a quadratic $f(x)$ such that $f(1)=0$, $f(\omega)=1$ and $f(\omega^2)=2$, and then use $f(\omega^n)$. Here $\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}$.

Comment: @Henning: Yes :-) Thanks. Editing

Comment: I guess this is cheating: $a_0=0,a_1=1,a_2=2$ and $a_n=a_{n-3}$ for $n>2$. - However, we can then use the method to turn a linear recurrance into closed form, which should yield the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If complex exponentiation is OK, then you may do it. The map $f: n \mapsto \exp(2\pi n/3)$ takes ${\mathbb Z}$ to the three cubic roots of $1$:  $1$, $\gamma=\exp(2\pi i /3)$ and $\overline{\gamma}$. Now pick a polynomial $P$ that maps $1$ to $0$, $\gamma$ to $1$ and $\overline{\gamma}$ to $2$. Then $P\circ f$ will do the job. Same principle for mod $N$.

Later edit: In the general case set $\gamma=\exp(2\pi i/N)$ and define $e_N(z)=\frac{1}{N} \left(z^{N-1}+z^{N-2} + \cdots +z +1\right) $. Then  $e_N$ maps $1$ to $1$ but every $\gamma^k$, $1\leq k<N$ to zero. The wanted function is then:
$$ h_N(n) = \sum_{k=1}^N k \ e_N \left( \ \gamma^{n-k}  \right), $$
which maps $n$ to $n\  (\mbox{mod}\; N)$. What is really happening here is that we are doing a forward + backward  Fourier transform of the modulus function.

Comment: Excellent idea that generalizes!

Answer (score -1):

$\frac{3t^2 - t}{2i\sqrt{3}}$ where $t=e^{2\pi in/3} + e^{-2\pi in/3}$

Comment: If $3 \mid n$, then $t = 1 + 1 = 2$, and the expression equals $\frac{5}{i\sqrt{3}}$. Otherwise, $t = \omega + \omega^2 = -1$, and the expression equals $\frac{2}{i\sqrt{3}}$. When you give an answer without any explanation, it's hard to see what you meant to say or deduce from the context how to fix what you wrote.